# How to merge text from columns with same name into a unique column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to parse a whois database file with the following format, where each "inetnum" with its following attributes represents a row in my final table.
The file looks like this:

```
inetnum:        inetnum_example1
netname:        netname_example1
descr:          descr_example1
descr:          descr_example1
status:         status_example1
mnt-by:         mnt-by_example1
inetnum:        inetnum_example2
netname:        netname_example2
status:         status_example2
mnt-by:         mnt-by_example2
mnt-by:         mnt-by_example2
inetnum:        inetnum_example3
netname:        netname_example3
...
```

and the final result looks like this:

```
   row                    descr                  descr_1                  inetnum                   mnt-by                 mnt-by_1                  netname                   status
0    1           descr_example1           descr_example1         inetnum_example1          mnt-by_example1                      NaN         netname_example1          status_example1
1    2                      NaN                      NaN         inetnum_example2          mnt-by_example2          mnt-by_example2         netname_example2          status_example2
2    3                      NaN                      NaN         inetnum_example3                      NaN                      NaN         netname_example3                      NaN
```

To do so, I'm using the following script. However, as you can see some columns with the same name are labelled with a number and treated independently.

**My question is: As the column values will always be strings, is there a way to concatenate all the values from the columns with the same name into a single one?**
Using the previous example, the first row would only have a "descr" column with both previous values concatenated, and the same for the "mnt-by" column in the second row.

Desired output (delimiter can be any random char(set), as ',' in this case):

```
   row                    descr                     inetnum                   mnt-by                                netname                   status
   0    1           descr_example1,descr-example1   inetnum_example1          mnt-by_example1                       netname_example1          status_example1
   1    2                      NaN                  inetnum_example2          mnt-by_example2,mnt-by-example2       netname_example2          status_example2
   2    3                      NaN                  inetnum_example3          NaN                                   netname_example3          NaN
```

Any idea would be highly appreciated, thanks a lot for your time

Script:

```
import pandas
import sys
mydb = pandas.read_table(sys.argv[1], encoding="ISO-8859-1", header=None)
mydb.columns = ['data']
mydb = mydb['data'].str.split(': ',1,expand=True)
mydb = mydb.set_index([0,(mydb[0] == 'inetnum').cumsum().rename('row')])
mydb = mydb.set_index(mydb.groupby([0,'row']).cumcount(), append=True)
mydb = mydb.reset_index('row')
mydb.index = mydb.index.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
mydb = mydb.set_index(['row'], append=True)[1].unstack(0)
mydb = mydb.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_0')[0]).reset_index()
print(mydb)
```

Comment: Please post the desired output

Comment: You want to merge duplicate columns?

Comment: @meee yes, having 2 columns named "column_name" with different strings "string1" and "string2" i want one unique column "column_name" with value="string1,string2"

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right:

```
mydb['descr'] = mydb['descr'] + ', ' + mydb['descr_1']
```

Comment: @meee thanks a lot for your answers, but I would like to do it in a generic way, where I don't know which columns will be duplicated. For each row (or each repeated line in the original file inside the same "node"), remove any duplicated resulting column and merge its values. Sorry if I was not clear enough, hope this will clarify

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
from itertools import combinations

same = [(i, j) for i,j in combinations(mydb, 2) if mydb[i].equals(mydb[j])]
print(same) #list of tuples, each tuple show duplicate columns

for i in same:
    mydb[i[0]] = mydb[i[0]].astype(str) + ', ' + mydb[i[1]].astype(str)
    mydb.drop([i[1]], inplace = True, axis = 1)
    
mydb
```

Comment: this works really good but only for the first tuple of duplicated columns, "descr" in this case. but after, "mnt-by" is still parsed as 2 columns. when executing "print(same)" it only prints "descr" and "descr_1", so somehow the next tuples are not detected. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Telford15 "next tuples are not detected?" Yes, not detected, because in your dataframe there are only two columns with same content (descr, descr_1).

Comment: there is also "mnt-by" and "mnt-by_1" in the second row

Answer (score 0):

Final snippet:

```
mydb = pandas.read_table(dbfile, encoding="ISO-8859-1", header=None)
mydb.columns = ['data']
mydb = mydb['data'].str.split(r':\s*',1,expand=True)
mydb = mydb.set_index([0,(mydb[0] == delimiter).cumsum().rename('register')])
mydb = mydb.groupby([0,'register'], sort=False).agg(" || ".join)
mydb = mydb.reset_index('register')
mydb = mydb.set_index(['register'], append=True)[1].unstack(0)
mydb = mydb.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split()[0]).reset_index()
```